# Laravel 5 passing data to view from other domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2

I want to know if its possible for my Application in **domain1** to `forward data to the view from other` **domain2**. So that `every changes made specially in database in my domain1`, the `domain2 can get it or display it`. I only needed some views to display in my domain2. If anyone knows this is possible I want to know the way to achieve this.

Comment: You can make an ajax call every 5 or 10 sec. to fetch updated data from database through setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can make an api call to domain1 from domain2 whenever the change happens with some private hash.

http://domain2.com/change-data?data1=sssss&data2=kdkdkdkkd&api_key=asdfghjklkjhfdsqwertyu

you can make use of laravel events for the same so taht whenever a data change is happening you can fire and event whose listner calls the api for the next domain